# Ebean delete object not refresh realtionship

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

The following problem makes me confused. I would like to delete an measurement value from an relationship and the referenced object should bee update the measurements. So what is my problem, if I delete an measurement, that works fine, but if I get the all measurements from cure object, I see that the delete object is inside. What is the best ways to refresh the relationship?

Measurement.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "measurements")
public class Measurement extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    public Date created = new Date();

    @Constraints.Required
    public double weight;

    @Constraints.Required
    public double belly;

    @Constraints.Required
    public double thigh;

    @Constraints.Required
    public double gluteal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    public Cure cure;
}
```

Cure.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cures")
public class Cure extends Model  implements Comparable<Cure> {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    public Date created = new Date();

    public int startHour = 10;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    public Challenge challenge;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany
    public List<Measurement> measurements;
}
```

My action that should bee handle the delete

```
public static Result delete(Long id){
    Measurement measurement = Measurement.find.byId(id);

    if(measurement == null && !measurement.belongsToUser(user)){
        return noContent();
    }

    measurement.delete();
    return ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i didn't see the finder in your models class. Implement those as follow

```
public static Finder<Long, Measurement> find = new Finder<Long, Measurement>(Long.class, Measurement.class);
```

then try. Also ebean has lots of issue you can use raw query to delete as follow

```
SqlUpdate deletObject = Ebean
                        .createSqlUpdate("delete from table_name where id = "
                                + id); 
deletObject.execute();
```